# Test whether a function can be used

Tags: bash

Is it possible to test whether a function can be used, in case the file in which the function resides has not been sourced ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to ensure that a particular command is a shell function, as opposed to an alias, built in command, keyword or external command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test the result of

```
type functionname

$ if type existingfunction >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi
yes
$

$ if type nonexistingfunction >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi
no
$
```

Comment: In my bash version: "-f suppress shell function lookup". Can't do a " ! -f ", unfortunately.

Comment: Can I include the test with a function call, so that I can use a test to execute some command ?

Comment: In the examples I gave, the echo's are commands you can replace with any other command. "if type myfunction >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then . myfunction.rc ; myfunction arguments ; else myfunction arguments; fi"

Comment: Right, it is already a condition. thank you.  Why is the ` >/dev/null 2>&1 ` necessary ?

Comment: sorry: I meant `type -t`

Comment: @Veak the "> /dev/null 2>&1" are needed to prevent the command from putting unneeded and possibly confusing text on the screen. The test is on just the returncode of the "type functionname" command.

Comment: @JJoao That -t would work too, though you would have to put in an additional test for the the return value being equal to "function". Good find. Didn't know that one.

Answer (score 5):

In `bash` (or `ksh` where that syntax comes from, or `zsh`¹), you can do:

```
if typeset -f myfunction > /dev/null; then
  echo The myfunction function is defined
fi
```

That also works in ksh (where that syntax is from) and zsh.

In `zsh`, you can also do:

```
if (( $+functions[myfunction] )) then
  echo The myfunction function is defined
fi
```

That is test for the presence of `myfunction` in the special associative array that maps function names to their definition (both approaches also work for autoloadable functions that have not been loaded yet).

Note that if there also happens to be an alias by that same, in order to be able to use the function by the same name, you'd have to quote it or at least part of it (`'cmd' args` instead of `cmd args`). Same would apply to shell reserved words, but bash doesn't let you define functions by the same name as reserved words anyway.

As suggested by @JJao in comments, you could also use `type -t` (in bash or recent versions of ksh93) to tell you what type of command `myfunction` is.

```
case $(type -t myfunction) in
  (function) echo OK;;
  (alias) echo might exist as a function but it is first an alias;;
  (*) echo cannot be used as a function;;
esac
```

---

<sup>¹ With `yash`, the API is slightly different, `typeset -f myfunction` returns *true* and produces no output when the function is defined, and otherwise returns *false* and outputs an error message. You need `typeset -pf myfunction` to print the definition of the function in yash (also works in ksh/zsh/bash, though the `-p` is not necessary there). So there, you'd need `if typeset -f myfunction 2> /dev/null`. Doing `if typeset -f myfunction > /dev/null 2>&1` would make it portable to all four shells.</sup>

Comment: This then gets to the problem on whether to use `typeset` or `type`.

Comment: Which one to use and under what circumstance?

Comment: From my point of view it looks that `type` is the more appropriate to use than `typeset`.

Comment: @Veak, `type` wlll tell you whether a keyword, builtin, alias, function, external command exists by that name, `typeset -f` tells you whether a *function* exists by that name. `typeset -f` is closer to what you asked, but `type` might be closer to what you need/want.

Comment: As the result is concerned, `type -f` also tells me whether a function exists by that name.  Or not necessarily.  Could I actually rely on one or the other without worry?

Comment: @Veak: `type -f` tells you whether *something other than a function* exists by that name. In other words, `-f` means "ignore shell functions."

Comment: Note that `typeset` is an alias for `declare` and considered obsolete, according to Bash  help. Besides that, IMHO, using a secondary effect of "if I declare this name as function and it doesn't give an error" is not a good programming practice for this, against asking "Is this name a function?" with the `type` builtin, designed with that purpose.

Comment: @Fjor, `typeset` is the original name from ksh and is  also supported by zsh and yash. bash choosing a different name here is silly. `typeset` is there to stay in bash, I'm not going to start using `declare`. `typeset -f name` reports the definition of the function by that name and returns with failure if there's no such function so is one of the right ways to check if there's such a function. `type -t name` does not do that. It reports the type of `name` if found as a command / keyword and again failure if no command / keyword is found by that name.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas Thanks. Always is good to know the differences between shells.

Answer (score 0):

For readability of code and precision I do prefer

```
if [[ "$(type -t myfunction)" = "function" ]] ; then
   # the function is defined and accesible
fi
```

according to the description of `type` builtin in `help type` or `man bash`. Using only `type text` will search also in alias, builtins, files, etc., and can return 0 (true) for an undesired kind of object.

Comment: Note that it was already mentioned in my answer (first suggested by @JJao in comments)

Comment: Your'e right. @Jjao's comment were hidden and I forgot to expand all.